# Easy way to automate running same python script across several EC2 instances?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2

I have 4 linux EC2 instances created from the same AMI that I use to process files in S3.
I run the same python script on each instance. It takes a directory of files in S3 to process and a number telling it which files it is supposed to process.
Say mydir contains myfile1 ... myfile8.

On instance 0 I call:
python process.py mydir 0
This causes it to process myfile1 and myfile5.

On instance 1 I call:
python process.py mydir 1
This causes it to process myfile2 and myfile2.

And so on.

Inside the script I do:
keys = keys[pid::4] where pid is the argument from the command line.

I redistribute changes to my python script by syncing from S3.

Is there a simple way to automate this further?
I would like to press one button and say dir=yourdir and have it sync code from s3 and run on each instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/).
Example taken from Fabric documentation:

```py
from fabric import Connection
result = Connection('web1.example.com').run('uname -s', hide=True)
msg = "Ran {0.command!r} on {0.connection.host}, got stdout:\n{0.stdout}"
print(msg.format(result))

# Output:
# Ran 'uname -s' on web1.example.com, got stdout:
# Linux
```